# Efficient way to find extreme matrix coefficients in Gurobi model

Tags: python, gurobi

I am looking for a more efficient way to identify extreme matrix coefficients in a Gurobi model after (!) the model has been built. With "extreme" I mean particularly small or large coefficients that negatively influence the numeric performance of the model. The following code is extremely slow since it queries all coefficients:

```
    mdl.update()
    for c in mdl.getConstrs():
        c_name = c.ConstrName
        for v in mdl.getVars():
            v_name = v.VarName
            coefficient = mdl.getCoeff(c, v)
            if (coefficient != 0.0 and abs(coefficient) < 10e-4) or abs(coefficient) > 10e7:
                # Do something
```

I imagine that `Model.getA()` might help, but for some reason calling that function raises an error.

Comment: Without an understanding of what mdl is and/or what format the ```mdl.getConstrs() ```` returns data as well as without an understanding of what you define as a 'extreme matrix coefficient', it is not possible to answer this question.  As indicated in [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") your question needs a proper  Introduction that provides the context of your problem and the  the simplest data and code which reproduces your problem in a form that a respondent can copy and paste into their environment.

Comment: @itprorh66: anyone familiar with Gurobi knows what these things are. I did integrate a hint regarding "extreme coefficients" as you advised.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the maximum and/or minimum coefficient values of the matrix, just query the [MaxCoeff](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/maxcoeff.html) or [MinCoeff](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/mincoeff.html) attributes, respectively. Alternately, if you need to inspect all matrix coefficients, you *will* need to iterate over all coefficients, but it can be done much more efficiently by only iterating over the nonzero coefficients. I believe this will do what you need:

```
for c in mdl.getConstrs():
  row = mdl.getRow(c)
  for i in range(row.size()):
    coefficient = row.getCoeff(i)
    if (coefficient != 0.0 and abs(coefficient) < 1e-4) or abs(coefficient) > 1e7:
      bigvar = row.getVar(i)
      # Do something
```